# Запрос возвращает неверные данные

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

в MS ACCESS Запрос

`SELECT 
SalesByTYPE.TYPE, SalesByTYPE.KILK, SalesByTYPE.WART
FROM SalesByTYPE;`

возвращает такой набор:

> TYPE  KILK    WART
>
> LD    4000    3000
>
> HD    2000    7000

Хочу то же получить в C#, мой код

```
private static string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=tgdb.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password = pwd;";
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM SalesByTYPE";
    using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(SQL, conn))
    {
        using (OleDbDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    answer += $"{reader[0]} :\t{reader[1]} ,\t{reader[2]} .\n";
                }
                Console.WriteLine(answer);
            }
            else // 
            {
                answer = $"Error During Getting The Database Answer";
                Console.WriteLine(answer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В результате выполнения кода получаю:

> LD 6000 10000

т.е. первую ячейку первой строки и суммированые значения столбцов. Но почему и как исправить?

Comment: Значит столбцы не соответствуют порядку SalesByTYPE.TYPE, SalesByTYPE.KILK, SalesByTYPE.WART

Comment: В любой не понятной ситуации запускай дебаггер и смотри промежуточные значения.

Comment: @АртёмОконечников как именно не соответствуют? ведь запрос `SELECT * FROM SalesByTYPE` не учитывает порядка

Comment: @ГеннадийП что в дебаггере смотреть? Цикл While выполняется один раз, хотя должен 2 раза проходить

Comment: Смотрите таблицу SalesByTYPE, а именно её колонки. Если запихать ваш запрос выше в код (тот, который `...SalesByTYPE.TYPE, SalesByTYPE.KILK, SalesByTYPE.WART...`), то всё правильно работает?

Comment: @АртёмОконечников Да, в Accesse что `...SalesByTYPE.TYPE, SalesByTYPE.KILK, SalesByTYPE.WART...` что `... SELECT *...` возвращают одинаковый результат

Comment: Есть возможность опубликовать базу данных?

Comment: Нет, она использует таблицы c локальных серверов. Или я не понимаю как опубликовать без конфиденц инфы

Comment: @AleksandrH. Если цикл выполняется только один раз - значит результат возвращает только одну строку, значит либо что то не верно либо с запросом, либо с базой. Вы пробовали вставлять полный запрос как в Access `SELECT SalesByTYPE.TYPE, SalesByTYPE.KILK, SalesByTYPE.WART FROM SalesByTYPE;` ?

Comment: @ГеннадийП, Да, так само 1 строка. Наверное с базой косяк, потому что, если сохранить `SalesByType` как таблицу, то тянет все верно

Comment: Хотел перед выборкой, создать таблицу из `SalesByTYPE`. Запустил `SQL = "SELECT SalesByTYPE.* INTO [tmp] FROM SalesByTYPE";  OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SQL, conn);` но создалася таблица с 1 строкой. Отож проблема именно в том как студия выполняет `Select * From SalesByTYPE`

Comment: @АртёмОконечников, записал видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46bucc8aeyI работы кода